# How to get all the values from a FilteringSelect in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a FilteringSelect called **select**, and the values are being added from different places. At one point of time, I wanted to access all the values from the FilteringSelect.

In order to get a single value, I can use **select.get('value')**. But I wanted to have all the values in an array. In jQuery, we can do something like below,

```
var values = $('#select').val();    //returns an array
```

So, how to do the same in dojo?

Comment: What do you mean by "populated from different places"?

Comment: I mean the <option> is being added from different places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the list of 'options' in the FilteringSelect you can inspect the data element of the store.

e.g.

```
define([dijit/registry'], function(registry) {
    // this will return an array of options
    registry.byId('select').get('store').data;
});
```

happy coding.